# extern problems with array of structures c++

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2008, arrays, data-structures

I have the main .cpp file with this:

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include "Form1.h"
#include <iostream>
...
#include <stdio.h>

const int MAX_LEN = 1000;

struct DataLine {
    char StartCode;
    int ByteCount;
    int Address;
    int RecType;
    int DBytes[16];
    int Checksum;
};
DataLine AllData[MAX_LEN];
```

Then I have a form.h with the following:

```
extern const int MAX_LEN;  
extern struct DataLine AllData[MAX_LEN]; 
//later on in header file  
AllData[index].Startcode = sc;
AllData[index].ByteCount = i_Byte_Count;  
...
```

This will not compile giving a host of errors but the first is: `'DataLine *' : unknown size`. Should I change certain things to typedef? I'm not really sure why its not liking this.

Comment: I'm not sure `extern const int MAX_LEN = 4033;` makes a lot of sense.  If it's an `extern` variable, you shouldn't be giving it a value!

Comment: Ahh yes. I fixed that. Still have the same errors.

Comment: The main problem has been addressed by the answers given by others.  However, I thought I should point out that your header file is a bit weird in other ways.  It doesn't make any sense to perform assignments (e.g. `AllData[index].StartCode = sc;`) in a header unless you happen to be `#include`-ing it directly into the body of a function.

Comment: Well its a windows form application and when I tried to assign button_click, etc, it placed it in the Form1.h file so thats what I've been working out of. Should I move this to the cpp file?

Comment: Oh, if you have inline class member functions in your header file, then it does make sense...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't define

```
extern struct DataLine AllData[MAX_LEN];
```

in the header file because `struct DataLine` is completely unknown in the header file. No `typedef` will help you here. The definition of `struct DataLine` must be present in the header file before you define `AllData`. Move it there.

Answer (score 1):

Because the declaraction of struct DataLine has to be form.h before the definition of `AllData`

Basically, you are saying to your other files, that they could say:

```
 DataLine* pre = &AllData[5];
```

Now, how could the compiler know where far from the start of `AllData` that item is, unless it knows exactly how big each DataLine is?